# Atom (IDE): Trying to remove package

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, jsx

Working on React jsx code that looks like this (in Atom IDE)

For some reason, `networks` and `People` are marked as red (and a bunch of other keywords), and I want to figure out which of the Atom packages I installed is causing this. Is there a simple way to figure out which package is causing this?

[image: in Atom]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Packages Installed, and then Disable a couple of them (do not remove them, just Disabled).

Disable a couple of them until face the package with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Open up the Settings View using `Ctrl+,`, click on the "Install" tab and type your search query into the box under Install Packages.

See: https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/atom-packages/